# Setting up Troposphere with Aurora

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, troposphere

I'm trying to set up Aurora using Troposphere and can't find any good examples online.  Can anyone provide a good example of an Aurora Troposphere setup?

Answer (score 3):

In order to set up aurora, you should make sure you have a db instance and db cluster set up correctly. Below is a code snippet for setting up aurora in a VPC.

```
pipelinedbcluster = rds.DBCluster(
        title='PipelineDBCluster',
        DatabaseName=<your-db-name>,
        DBClusterIdentifier=<your-cluster-name>,
        DBSubnetGroupName=<your-subnet-group>,
        DBClusterParameterGroupName='default.aurora-postgresql9.6',
        DeletionProtection=False,
        Engine='aurora-postgresql',
        EngineVersion='9.6.8',
        MasterUsername=<your-username>,
        MasterUserPassword=<your-password>,
        Port=5432,
        VpcSecurityGroupIds=<your-primary-vpc-id>, #(required if creating aurora cluster in a VPC)
    )
pipelinedb = rds.DBInstance(
        title='PipelineDBInstance',
        DBInstanceIdentifier=<your-instance-name>,
        DBClusterIdentifier=Ref(pipelinedbcluster),
        DBInstanceClass='db.r4.large',
        Engine='aurora-postgresql',
        EngineVersion='9.6.8',
        PubliclyAccessible=False,
        Tags=<your-tags>,
        AutoMinorVersionUpgrade=True,
        StorageType='aurora'
    )
```

- add the above two resources in the template of troposphere.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Aurora blueprints [here](https://github.com/remind101/stacker_blueprints/tree/master/stacker_blueprints/rds).